# Hibernate Elasticsearch Search Type dfs_query_then_fetch

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate 5.3/Hibernate Search 5.10 and Elasticsearch 5.6.
I want to use **dfs_query_then_fetch** as default search type when searching.

Is there a way to set this default search type in elasticsearch or is there a way to configure Hibernate Search to use this parameter in its search request?

Either way is fine by me.

The elasticsearch docs say

> Don’t use dfs_query_then_fetch in production. It really isn’t required

but I use the score for sorting, combined with another sorting field. If virtually same scores are not returned as same scores, the sorting results are not as expected.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up to configure Elasticsearch using only one shard for my index. As a result, I also get the result scores I am looking for.

Using a single shard is ok with me, since there are not big loads of data in my index.

Answer (score 1):

No, Hibernate Search 5 doesn't allow this level of customization of your queries.

We are interested in use cases for query customization in Search 6, though, so be sure to create a JIRA ticket so that we can see what we can do: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately Search 6 will not be an option in the near future. At least not until Spring Data supports newer Hibernate versions.

Comment: Created a JIRA ticket: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3496